# Bestpractice for multiple GWT-RPC calls

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have to make several GWT-RPC calls.
I would like to start them asynchronously like this.

```
service.s1(param1, callback1);
service.s2(param2, callback2);
service.s3(param3, callback3);
```

I´m not sure how to "sync" the three callbacks.
The next action, e.g. call method nextMethod(); shall be done after the three callbacks are done.
Is there a "best practice" how to do this?

I thought to build a little serviceclass like this

```
public class ServiceSync
{ private boolean[] callReady;

  public ServiceSync(int n)
  { callReady = new boolean[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {  callReady[i]=false;
    }
  }

  public boolean setReady(int i)
  { callReady[i]=true;
    for(boolean b : callReady)
    { if (!b) return false;    
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

in the callback I would then say

```
if (serviceSync.setReady(myId))
{ nextMethod();}
```

but I´m not sure, if that´s a good idea. 
especially I´m not sure not to run in a problem, if 2 callbacks are calling this scrviceclass"at the same time"

Comment: do you want to call a method after another, I mean does the second call depends on the data returned by the first call?

Comment: no, the calls shall be "in parallel", I think the code does that. Is that true?

Comment: so you want to execute a method after and only in the case all three calls succeed, but you send the calls in parallel, right? if so your code is not clear that does what you say, what code do you have in the callback1, callback2 and callback3?

Comment: the callbacks store the received data.

Comment: ok, posted my response

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is the typical case which can be solved with [Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_%28programming%29).

Following the principle of DRY, instead of writing my own code, I would use the [gwtquery Promises](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Promises) solution, which has been written for gwt, based on the popular jQuery Deferred implementation.

In your case your code could look like:

```
    // Create 3 promises to be used in RPC
    PromiseRPC<String> promise1 = new PromiseRPC<String>();
    PromiseRPC<String> promise2 = new PromiseRPC<String>();
    PromiseRPC<String> promise3 = new PromiseRPC<String>();

    // Fire the asynchronous requests
    greetingService.greetServer(textToServer1, promise1);
    greetingService.greetServer(textToServer2, promise2);
    greetingService.greetServer(textToServer3, promise3);

    GQuery
          // 'when' returns a new promise which monitors all of its subordinates
          .when(promise1, promise2, promise3)
          // 'done' will be executed only in the case all promises succeed
          .done(new Function() {
            public void f() {
              // each promise store its result in a fixed position of the argument list
              String textFromServer1 = arguments(0, 0);
              String textFromServer2 = arguments(1, 0);
              String textFromServer3 = arguments(2, 0);
            }
          });

    // If you want you could fire requests here instead than above
```

Comment: very smart solution, I just did discover gquery some days ago and it seems an essential tool when developing with GWT

Comment: @Manolo, can you please help me? I tried this approach, But seems in case any one service call fails - we can't get any result except exception from failed service.

Comment: You have to use the `fail` method then to see what happened: GQuery.when(...).done(...).fail(new Function(){public void f(){console.log(dumpArguments())}});

Answer (score 2):

Declare a receiver with state for your callbacks, something like:

```
public class CallResultReceiver {

   boolean call1Done, call2Done, call3Done;

   public void onCall1Success() { 
      call1Done = true;
      if (call1Done && call2Done && call3Done) { doGreatThings(); }
   }

   public void onCall2Success() { 
      call2Done = true;
      if (call1Done && call2Done && call3Done) { doGreatThings(); }
   }

   public void onCall3Success() { 
      call3Done = true;
      if (call1Done && call2Done && call3Done) { doGreatThings(); }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not functionally very different, but it's much cleaner and easier to read imo.

Answer (score 1):

He is an best article on [Parallel asynchronous calls in GWT](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2010/11/29/parallel-asynchronous-calls-in-gwt/.)

By writing a simple ParentCallBack you can make your thing easy and efficient.

```
public void someGwtClientSideMethod() {   
  SomeServiceAsync someService = GWT.create(SomeService.class);  
  ParallelCallback fooCallback = new ParallelCallback();  
  ParallelCallback barCallback = new ParallelCallback();  
  ParentCallback parent = new ParentCallback(fooCallback, barCallback) {   
    public void handleSuccess() {  
      doSomething(getCallbackData(0), getCallbackData(1));  
    }  
  };  
  someService.foo(fooCallback);  
  someService.bar(barCallback);  
}
```

Here is the [Code for Parent Callback](http://www.bennorthrop.com/code/gwt-parallel-async/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach for presented issue:

Firstly, we'll need some sort of SynchronizedCounter to use in our parallel async issue:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {

    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Next step is to call RPC methods, e.g.:

```
private void fetchData() {
    getFirst();
    getSecond();
    getThird();
    getFourth();
}
```

Every RPC method would have to increment our counter before request and decrement it right after call success. Every RPC method will call final method after the RPC call, which will check requests' count, e.g.:

```
private void dataFetched() {
    if (counter.value() <= 0)
        // proceed
}
```

IMO very clear and elegant approach. Hope it helps.